# mixing Integer and Double in a conditional expression

Tags: java, integer, double, boxing, unboxing

From a Java book:

When mixing `Integer` and `Double` types in a conditional expression, then the `Integer` value is unboxed, promoted to `double`, and boxed into a `Double`:

```
    Integer a = 1;
    Double b = 2.0;
    System.out.println(true? a : b); // 1.0
```

For me, that was an unexpected result. How's That `Integer` is converted into a `Double` in this conditional expression?

Comment: You answered it yourself? It gets unboxed and then converted to double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the second and third operands of the conditional operator are numbers of differing types, [*binary numeric promotion*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) is applied, in order that they are of the same type.

In this case, `Double` is unboxed to `double`; `Integer` is unboxed to `int`, and then widened to `double`.

In other words, this is happening:

```
System.out.println(true? (double) a.intValue() : b.doubleValue());
```

This is just how the conditional operator is defined to behave.

---

Note that this behaviour is considered egregious enough that it is [a compiler error in Google's Java code](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/ConditionalExpressionNumericPromotion).

If you want to keep the operands as their "actual" types, you would need to cast them, say, to `Number`:

```
System.out.println(true ? (Number) a : (Number) b);
```

would print `1`.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, it's related to the Java compiler, if you have this line of code:

```
  Integer x = true?a:b;
```

it will have compile error, you have to either cast to Integer to change x to Double, since the compiler not check the conditional expression until runtime, the result could be Double, in your case the System.out.println is actually print a double.

Hope that answer your question.